# getting errors when creating a dynamic where clause

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting quite a few errors when trying to create a dynamic where clause using mysqli:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type
>   definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in ... on
>   line 318
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (HY000/2031): No data supplied for
>   parameters in prepared statement in ... on line 327
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): (HY000/2031): No data supplied
>   for parameters in prepared statement in ... on line 330
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt::store_result(): (HY000/2014): Commands out of
>   sync; you can't run this command now in ... on line 331

Im guessing there is a little change that is needed to solve the problems but what happens is that if one of the two drop down menu's do not equal `All` or if both  don't equal `All` then it comes up with the errors.

Below is the code display both the drop down menus and the query (with dynamic where clause) that follows depending n options selected:

```
   function ShowAssessment()
{   

$studentactive = 1;

$currentstudentqry = "
SELECT
st.StudentId, st.StudentAlias, st.StudentForename, st.StudentSurname
FROM
Student_Session ss 
INNER JOIN
Student st ON ss.StudentId = st.StudentId
WHERE
(ss.SessionId = ? and st.Active = ?)
ORDER BY st.StudentAlias
";

global $mysqli;
$currentstudentstmt=$mysqli->prepare($currentstudentqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$currentstudentstmt->bind_param("ii",$_POST["session"], $studentactive);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$currentstudentstmt->execute(); 
$currentstudentstmt->bind_result($dbStudentId,$dbStudentAlias,$dbStudentForename,$dbStudentSurname);
$currentstudentstmt->store_result();
$studentnum = $currentstudentstmt->num_rows();       

if($studentnum == 0){ ?>

<div class="red">
There are no Students who have currently taken this Assessment
</div>
<?php } else { 

$questionsqry = "
SELECT
QuestionId, QuestionNo
FROM
Question
WHERE
(SessionId = ?)
ORDER BY QuestionNo
";

global $mysqli;
$questionsstmt=$mysqli->prepare($questionsqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$questionsstmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["session"]);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$questionsstmt->execute(); 
$questionsstmt->bind_result($dbQuestionId,$dbQuestionNo);
$questionsstmt->store_result();
$studentnum = $questionsstmt->num_rows();      

        ?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">         
<p>
 <input type="hidden" name="module" value="<?php echo $_POST['module']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="session" value="<?php echo $_POST['session']; ?>">
<strong>Student:</strong>
<select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
<option value="All">All</option>
<?php
while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {
$stu = $dbStudentId;
if(isset($_POST["student"]) && $stu == $_POST["student"]) 
    echo "<option selected='selected' value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo "<option value='$stu'>" . $dbStudentAlias . " - " . $dbStudentForename . " " . $dbStudentSurname . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Question:</strong>
<select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
<option value="All">All</option>
<?php
while ( $questionsstmt->fetch() ) {
$ques = $dbQuestionId;
if(isset($_POST["question"]) && $ques == $_POST["question"]) 
    echo "<option selected='selected' value='$ques'>" . $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo "<option value='$ques'>" . $dbQuestionNo . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</select>
</p>

<input id="answerSubmit" type="submit" value="Get Student's Answers" name="answerSubmit" />
</form>

<?php
}
}

function StudentAnswersIsSubmitted()
{

if(!isset($_POST["answerSubmit"]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else // All is ok
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

function StudentAnswers()
{

$selectedstudentanswerqry = "
SELECT
StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer
ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, StudentMark
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (s.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
";

// Initially empty
$where = array('q.SessionId = ?');
$parameters = array($_POST["session"]);
$parameterTypes = 'i';

// Check whether a specific student was selected
if($_POST["student"] !== 'All') {
    $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
    $parameters[] = $_POST["student"];
    $parameterTypes .= 'i';
}

// Check whether a specific question was selected
// NB: This is not an else if!
if($_POST["question"] !== 'All') {
    $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
    $parameters[] = $_POST["question"];
    $parameterTypes .= 'i';
}

// If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
// our query
if(!empty($where)) {
    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    global $mysqli;
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes,implode($parameters));  //LINE 318
}

$selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
  GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
  ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
";

// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); //LINE 327
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname,$detailsSessionId,$detailsQuestionNo, 
$detailsQuestonContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsNoofAnswers,$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsQuestionMarks,$detailsStudentAnswer,$detailsResponseTime,
$detailsMouseClick,$detailsStudentMark); //LINE 330
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result(); //LINE 331
$selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows();     

echo "$selectedstudentanswerqry";

}

?>
```

Comment: Check the output value of the array you are passing to bind_params: `var_dump(array_merge(array($parameterTypes), $parameters)));`

Comment: @andho The result of the var dump when I chose session (assessment) with value `31`, student number value `40`, and question number value `81`, AND WHERE CLAUSE `WHERE q.SessionId = ? AND sa.StudentId = ? AND q.QuestionId = ?`, I am getting this output: `array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "iii" [1]=> string(2) "31" [2]=> string(2) "40" [3]=> string(2) "81" } `

Comment: @andho have you got any ideas on this because I am struggling

Comment: no idea. What you should do is isolate the offencing code and try test it.

Comment: Start with the simplest thing you can possibly do, and start building up to what you currently have, testing at each step. What I would do is, write the prepared statement statically and send the bind_params manually as a first step. 2nd step: try to make the bind_params automatic...and so on.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [fluentPDO](http://fluentpdo.com/documentation.html#gettingStarted), Dibi fluent or some similar query builder. It will save you from a lot of misery and they already solved what you are trying to do.

Anyway, instead of:

```
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes,implode($parameters));
```

use:

```
call_user_func_array(array($selectedstudentanswerstmt, 'bind_param'),
    array_merge(array($parameterTypes), $parameters))
```

Comment: MY query works fine when I echo it, it is just giving me errors which means I am just doing something slightly wrong in my practice

Comment: You have trouble with binding parameters to the query. '?' do not match with bind_param calls. Problem is with that implode. You have to use call_user_func_array(array($selectedstudentanswerstmt, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($parameterTypes), $parameters)) instead.

Comment: Can you change your answer to include the `call_user_func_array(...` so that I know how it is implemented correctly

Comment: I included demo in question as well

Comment: Please look at update, still got errors when trying your answer

Comment: Just use that library I recomended. Then you will not see these errors ever again and your code will be cut to one third. In this mess you will not be able to do any modifications in future.

Comment: I can't use the library, I will clean code up give me time, I had to run an errand

Comment: Why you can't use the library?

Comment: I have already made loads of queries without the builder and this is last query so may as well finish it off manualy

Comment: Code updated, cleaned, commented displaying where errors are, the errors it refers to are in the update